# Creating a data entry form with selectizeGroupUI to enter data into a data table (SQL)

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, grouping, selectize.js

I am creating a ShinyApp to enter data into a table that is part of a database (SQL). The data entry form should allow the selection of two variables whereas the second depends on the first (information on the relationship of the two variables is stored in another datatable). If I use  selectizeGroupUI() the following error is produced: 'error in evaluating the argument 'value' in selecting a method for function 'dbWriteTable': arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1'.

If I replace the two variables that I would want to specify via selectizeGroupUI() with selectInput(), it does not produce any error and works fine (commented in the code), but then obviously I cannot use the conditional sub setting, which I need to have.

SQL Code to create the database:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestSelectizeGroupUI;
USE TestSelectizeGroupUI;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;
CREATE TABLE data(
  data_id                 INT           NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  study_id                INT,  
  covariate_id            INT,          
  quantity                DECIMAL,    
  standard_deviation      VARCHAR(50),  
  sample_size             VARCHAR(50),   
  /* Keys */
    primary key(data_id)
  );

DROP USER IF EXISTS 'admin'@localhost;
CREATE USER 'admin'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'adminPassword!';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TestSelectizeGroupUI.* TO 'admin'@localhost;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

R Shiny App using ShinyWidget and the SelectizeGroupUI function and producing the error mentioned above. I would greatly appreciate if someone succeeds to fix it. Credits for the code go to Niels van der Velden as I have adapted most of the code based on https://www.nielsvandervelden.com/post/sql_datatable/editable-datatables-in-r-shiny-using-sql/

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI) #to connect to MariaDB
library(stringdist)
library(tidyr)
library(pool) 
library(shinyjs) #connects shiny to java scripts
library(uuid) #tools fo generating and handling of universally unique identifiers

Sys.setenv(TZ='CET')
Sys.setenv(ORA_SDTZ='CET')

labelMandatoryDat <- function(label) {
  tagList(
    label,
    span("*", class = "mandatory_star")
  )
}

appCSS <- ".mandatory_star { color: black; }"


#Connect to MariaDB that is stored locally
beeDB <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user="admin",password="adminPassword!",dbname="TestSelectizeGroupUI")

covariates_example <- data.frame(study_id=c(1,1,2),covariate_id=c(1,2,3))

#1. User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),
  fluidRow(column(width=2,align="right",strong("Data:",style = "font-size:19px;"),
                  actionButton("display_button_data", "Display table"),
                  actionButton("add_button_data", "Add", icon("plus")))
  ),
  br(),
    fluidRow(width="100%",
           dataTableOutput("data_table", width = "100%")
  ),
  
)

#2. Server Function

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    
    input$submit_data
    input$submit_edit_data
    input$delete_button_data
    dbReadTable(beeDB, "data")
    
  })
  
  fieldsMandatoryDat <- c("quantity")
  
  observe({
    
    mandatoryFilledDat <-
      vapply(fieldsMandatoryDat,
             function(x) {
               !is.null(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != ""
             },
             logical(1))
    mandatoryFilledDat <- all(mandatoryFilledDat)
    
    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "submit_data", condition = mandatoryFilledDat)
    
  })
  
  #Entry form data: Function for the entry form that will pop-up in a model dialog when the Add_data is clicked.
  entry_form_data <- function(button_id){
    
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        div(id=("entry_form_data"),
            tags$head(tags$style(".modal-dialog{ width:600px}")), #Modify the width of the dialog
            tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible}"))), 
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(
                splitLayout(
                  cellWidths = c("200px", "100px", "250px"),
                  cellArgs = list(),
                  selectizeGroupUI(
                    id = "my-filters",
                    inline = FALSE,
                    params = list(
                      study_id = list(inputId = "study_id", title = "study_id", placeholder = 'select'),
                      covariate_id = list(inputId = "covariate_id", title = "covariate_id", placeholder = 'select')
                    )
                  ),
                  #selectInput("study_id", "study_id",choices=c(1:3)),
                  #selectInput("covariate_id", "covariate_id",choices=c(1:5)),
                  numericInput("quantity", labelMandatoryDat("quantity"),NA,min=0.01,max=100000)),
                numericInput("standard_deviation", "standard_deviation",NA,min=0.01,max=100000),
                numericInput("sample_size", "sample_size",NA,min=1,max=100000),
                helpText(labelMandatoryDat(""), paste("Mandatory fields.")),
                actionButton(button_id, "Submit")
              ),
              easyClose = TRUE
            )
        )
      )
    )
  }
  #Add Data: Function to save the data into df format.
  
  formData_data <- reactive({
    formData_data <- data.frame(
      study_id=input$study_id,
      covariate_id=input$covariate_id,
      quantity=input$quantity,
      standard_deviation = input$standard_deviation,
      sample_size=input$sample_size,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    return(formData_data)
  })

 
  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters",
    data = covariates_example,
    vars = c("study_id", "covariate_id")
  )
  
  #Function to append data to the SQL table
  appendData_data <- function(data_data){
    dbWriteTable(beeDB,"data",data_data,append=T)
  }
  
  #When add_data button is clicked it will activate the entry_form with an action button called submit. Priority is added in order to make sure that no reactive values are updated until the event is finished.
  observeEvent(input$add_button_data, priority = 20,{
    entry_form_data("submit_data")
  })
  #When the submit button is clicked the formdata is appended to the SQL table, the values in the form are reset and the modal is removed.
  observeEvent(input$submit_data, priority = 20,{
    appendData_data(formData_data())
    shinyjs::reset("entry_form_data")
    removeModal()
  })
  
  #display output table: Render the DataTable. 
  output$data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(input$display_button_data == 0) {return()}
    else{
      table <- data() #req(res_mod()) #%>% select(-study_id) #show all columns, also study_id
      table <- datatable(table, 
                         rownames = FALSE,
                         caption = tags$caption("Data Table"),
                         options = list(searching = TRUE, lengthChange = TRUE, pageLength = 5, lengthMenu = c(5,10,50,100), dom = '<"top">t<"bottom"fli><"clear">') 
      )
    }
  })
  
  #to automatically disconnect from database after closing shinyApp
  values <- reactiveValues(sessionId = NULL)
  values$sessionId <- as.integer(runif(1, 1, 100000))
  output$sessionId <- renderText(paste0("Session id: ", values$sessionId))
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    observe(cat(paste0("Ended: ", values$sessionId)))
  })
  
}

#3. Run the APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it myself and as far as I have understood, the input entered into the entry form via selectizeGroupUI cannot be called by 'input$....' but has to be called via 'res_mod()$...' which is the name of the function that I have used to store the selected input. I therefore had to change my reactive with the name 'formData_data' from input$... to res_mod()$ for the first two lines that refer to the input from selectizeGroupUI.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI) #to connect to MariaDB
library(stringdist)
library(tidyr)
library(pool) #Enables the creation of object pools, which make it less computationally expensive to fetch a new object. Currently the only supported pooled objects are 'DBI' connections.
library(shinyjs) #connects shiny to java scripts
library(uuid) #tools fo generating and handling of universally unique identifiers

Sys.setenv(TZ='CET')
Sys.setenv(ORA_SDTZ='CET')

labelMandatoryDat <- function(label) {
  tagList(
    label,
    span("*", class = "mandatory_star")
  )
}

appCSS <- ".mandatory_star { color: black; }"


#Connect to MariaDB that is stored locally
beeDB <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), user="admin",password="adminPassword!",dbname="TestSelectizeGroupUI")

covariates_example <- data.frame(study_id=c(1,1,2),covariate_id=c(1,2,3))

#1. User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::inlineCSS(appCSS),
  fluidRow(column(width=2,align="right",strong("Data:",style = "font-size:19px;"),
                  actionButton("display_button_data", "Display table"),
                  actionButton("add_button_data", "Add", icon("plus")))
  ),
  br(),
  fluidRow(width="100%",
           dataTableOutput("data_table", width = "100%")
  ),
  
)

#2. Server Function

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    
    input$submit_data
    input$submit_edit_data
    input$delete_button_data
    dbReadTable(beeDB, "data")
    
  })
  
  fieldsMandatoryDat <- c("quantity")
  
  observe({
    
    mandatoryFilledDat <-
      vapply(fieldsMandatoryDat,
             function(x) {
               !is.null(input[[x]]) && input[[x]] != ""
             },
             logical(1))
    mandatoryFilledDat <- all(mandatoryFilledDat)
    
    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "submit_data", condition = mandatoryFilledDat)
    
  })
  
  #Entry form data: Function for the entry form that will pop-up in a model dialog when the Add_data and Edit_data buttons are pressed.
  entry_form_data <- function(button_id){
    
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        div(id=("entry_form_data"),
            tags$head(tags$style(".modal-dialog{ width:600px}")), #Modify the width of the dialog
            tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible}"))), #Necessary to show the input options
            fluidPage(
              fluidRow(
                splitLayout(
                  cellWidths = c("200px", "100px", "250px"),
                  cellArgs = list(),
                selectizeGroupUI(
                    id = "my-filters",
                    params = list(
                      study_id = list(inputId = "study_id", label="study_id", title = "study_id", placeholder = 'select'),
                      covariate_id = list(inputId = "covariate_id", label="covariate_id", title = "covariate_id", placeholder = 'select')
                    )
                  ),
              #  selectizeInput("study_id", "study_id",choices=covariates_example$study_id),
                #selectizeInput("covariate_id", "covariate_id",choices=covariates_example$covariate_id),
                   numericInput("quantity", labelMandatoryDat("quantity"),NA,min=0.01,max=100000)),
                numericInput("standard_deviation", "standard_deviation",NA,min=0.01,max=100000),
                numericInput("sample_size", "sample_size",NA,min=1,max=100000),
                helpText(labelMandatoryDat(""), paste("Mandatory fields.")),
                actionButton(button_id, "Submit")
              ),
              easyClose = TRUE
            )
        )
      )
    )
  }
  #Add Data: Function to save the data into df format. for the data data
  
  formData_data <- reactive({
    formData_data <- data.frame(
      study_id=res_mod()$study_id,
      covariate_id=res_mod()$covariate_id,
      quantity=input$quantity,
      standard_deviation = input$standard_deviation,
      sample_size=input$sample_size,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    return(formData_data)
  })
  
  
  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters",
    data = covariates_example,
    vars = c("study_id", "covariate_id")
  )
  
  #Function to append data to the SQL table
  appendData_data <- function(data_data){
       dbWriteTable(beeDB,"data",data_data,append=T)
  }
  
  #When add_data button is clicked it will activate the entry_form2 with an action button called submit. Priority is added in order to make sure that no reactive values are updated untill the event is finished.
  observeEvent(input$add_button_data, priority = 20,{
    entry_form_data("submit_data")
  })
  #When the submit button is clicked the formdata is appended to the SQL table, the values in the form are reset and the modal is removed.
  observeEvent(input$submit_data, priority = 20,{
    appendData_data(formData_data())
    shinyjs::reset("entry_form_data")
    removeModal()
  })
  
  #display output table: Render the DataTable. 
  output$data_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if(input$display_button_data == 0) {return()}
    else{
      table <- data() 
      table <- datatable(table, 
                         rownames = FALSE,
                         caption = tags$caption("Data Table"),
                         options = list(searching = TRUE, lengthChange = TRUE, pageLength = 5, lengthMenu = c(5,10,50,100), dom = '<"top">t<"bottom"fli><"clear">') 
      )
    }
  })
  
  #to automatically disconnect from database after closing shinyApp
  values <- reactiveValues(sessionId = NULL)
  values$sessionId <- as.integer(runif(1, 1, 100000))
  output$sessionId <- renderText(paste0("Session id: ", values$sessionId))
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    observe(cat(paste0("Ended: ", values$sessionId)))
  })
  
}

#3. Run the APP
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```